# How to use .iloc and .loc to get row data from specific columns value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matlab

I am trying to make a scatter plot of dataset, 1st column is + or -,  2nd column is X axis and 3rd columns is Y axis. I need to take positve x and y and plot them one color, and than take the negatives x and y and plot them another color.

```
     1  0.107143   0.60307
0    1  0.093318  0.649854
1    1  0.097926  0.705409
2    1  0.155530  0.784357
3    1  0.210829  0.866228
4    1  0.328341  0.929094
..  ..       ...       ...
805 -1  0.595622  0.871053
806 -1  0.625576  0.869298
807 -1  0.648618  0.857018
808 -1  0.637097  0.839474
809 -1  0.641705  0.804386

[810 rows x 3 columns]
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


d1 = pd.read_csv('data1.txt', sep='\s+')

y = d1[d1.iloc[:,2].values == -1]
x = d1[d1.iloc[:,1].values == 1]


y1 =  d1[d1.iloc[0:,2].values == -1]
x1 = d1[d1.iloc[0:,1].values == 1]

plt.scatter(x1, y1, color='red', marker='o', label='-1')
plt.scatter(x, y, color='blue', marker='x', label='+1')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')


plt.show()

print(y)
print(d1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with a solution which does not use `iloc` or `loc`, try this.
Only change is in getting the positive and negative rows. See comments inline

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0.807143, 0.60307],[-1, 0.207143, 0.50307],[1, 0.177143, 0.80307],[-1, 0.307143, 0.90307],[1, 0.107143, 0.6087]], columns=['val','x','y'])

# Get positive and negative values based on the colum
positive = df[df['val'] ==  1]
negative = df[df['val'] == -1]

#your existing code. Update X and Y values
plt.scatter(negative['x'], negative['y'], color='red', marker='o', label='-1')
plt.scatter(positive['x'], positive['y'], color='blue', marker='x', label='+1')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

**Output:**
[image]